# helicon ISAPI Rewrite - https/http/www

Tags: iis, rewrite, isapi-rewrite

How do I need to change this rule for IIS to support all variations of domain.

I want all traffic to go to `https://domaindotcom/folder/<personalisedID>` - we have sent a letter to ask recipients to go to `domaindotcom/<personalisedid>`. Therefore need this to redirect automatically to where these pages are actually located which is `https://domaindotcom/folder/<personalisedID>`.

This is what I have so far, but this doesn't cover all variations that a user could enter into their browser.

i.e. www.domaindotcom, domaindotcom, https://domaindotcom, http://domaindotcom

All advice would be greatly appreciated, I'm very new to all this so very much stabbing in the dark!

```
#Redirect non-HTTPS to HTTPS 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} domaindotcom [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*) 
RewriteRule .? https://domaindotcom/folder%1 [R,L]
```